# jQuery hover flickering

Tags: jquery, hover, flicker

I'm trying to get these arrows to show when hover over this slider I'm making. However, when doing so they seem to flicker like crazy. I tried everything and cannot get it sorted.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/hfK7NKtR

AND the HTML: http://pastebin.com/kQbJ3mDD

Example: http://www.matthewruddy.com/slider/slider.html

Comment: If you post a live demo at a collaborative site, such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), it makes it easier to help. =)

Comment: Tried to on JS fiddle, but for some reason I couldn't get it to work. The function wasn't working.

Comment: Also, can you post an example with low resolution images / image placeholders?

Comment: Sorry. Had forgotten to add an example. Have done now. :)

Comment: Please post example of 'working' code to jsFiddle or something like that. Did you add the right jQuery to the fiddle when trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense why it is flickering. You are binding hover to the container but next and prev are outside the container. When you mouse over the prev is sends mouseleave to container, then you move the mouse and since prev is hidden now it sends mouseenter but then the prev appears again and you move and it sends mouseleave etc...

You can try putting prev/next inside the container, setting the container to position relative then absolutely positioning them with relation to the container.

Or instead of hover monitor mouse movements and it the mouse is inside the container, show the prev/next, otherwise hide them.

You might be able to use some of the event properties jQuery exposes so you can cancel the mouseleave event when it occurs if the target is the next/prev but I haven't have much luck doing that in the past.

Comment: Thanks a million. Works perfectly! Didn't cop onto it myself. Thanks again. :)